# @Async won't worked on a mocked object's method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, asynchronous, mockito

I've got a Controller which in turn calls a Service method annotated with `@Async`. I want to write unite tests for the controller to verify that it returns promptly after calling the Service layer's asynchronous method. Usually when I'm testing a specific later I'd mock the layer below. This means that in this case I've got a mocked Service layer and it the `@Async` annotation won't work.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    // constructors and some fields
    public ResponseEntity myControllerMethod() {
        myService.asyncMethod(1);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();   
    }

}

@Service
public class MyService {
    // .. some fluff
    @Async
    public void asyncMethod(int bla) {
        // doing some work
    } 

}
```

Then I've got the unit tests for the controller.

```
@Mock private MyService myService;

@Test
public void test() {
        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                fail();
            }
            return null;
        }).when(myService).asyncMethod(1);

        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ResponseEntity r = myController.myControllerMethod();
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep to let executor service start

        assertEquals(200, r.getStatusCodeValue());
        verify(myService, times(1)).asyncMethod(1);
        assertTrue(after - before < 500); // verify time took for the controller to respond is significantly less than the wait time of asyncMethod

}
```

My test fails on the last assert because `asyncMethod` is not ran asynchronously, because `myService` is a Mocked object. Is there a way to preserve the `@Async` behaviour on Mockito objects? Or is there a better way to test this code in general, rather then using Mockito?

Comment: There is no such way you can retain Async behaviour on mock objects. The way you are tetsing is correct. Your test is failing because you are sleeping for 1000 ms and you are testing for < 500 which is obvious.

Comment: @pvpkiran well this was just a dummy value 500ms. It should still work because if the service call is done asynchronously then myControllerMethod should return in something like 20-30ms. Even if I change it to <1000ms still fails and the reason is that the service method is not ran asynchronously and I can verify this while debugging my code.

Comment: service call cannot be done asynchronously using mock. This is what I am trying to say. when asyncmethod is called(via your test case and then through controller ), the control will come to your answer, where you are sleeping for 1000 ms. So What I am trying to say is if you want your last statement in your test to get passed you can increase the time in your assert. Thats all